# How to make C++ templates work for Objective C types with ARC?

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, clang

Take a trivial example.  If I compile the following `main.mm` file without ARC, it works fine.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

template <typename T>
int testing(const T & whoCares) {
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return testing(@"hello");
}
```

If I compile this with ARC, the following error occurs:

```
/Users/sam/Projects/TemplateTest/TemplateTest/main.mm:10:12: error: no matching function for call to 'testing'
return testing(@"hello");
       ^~~~~~~
/Users/sam/Projects/TemplateTest/TemplateTest/main.mm:4:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = NSString *]
int testing(const T & whoCares) {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Why?  And more importantly, can it be worked around?  There isn't any further explanation for why the substitution fails.  If I explicitly pass the type, like so:

```
return testing<NSString *>(@"hello");
```

it works.  Having said that, I don't want to, and shouldn't have to do this all over my code.

What's also interesting is this only fails for Objective C types.  The following substitutions work fine regardless of ARC being enabled:

```
return testing("hello");
return testing(123);
```

Comment: Do you have the option of switching compilers in your version of Xcode and, if so, does it make a difference?

Comment: I do (I'm using Xcode 4.3.3).  However, I was under the impression that ARC only works with the Apple LLVM Compiler 3.1 setting (which is what I'm using).

Comment: Your example works fine with Clang version 3.2. I suspect that @SamCee's answer is correct and the bug has already been fixed.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Yes, you're right.  It was fixed when Apple shipped XCode 4.5

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is possibly a compiler bug with clang.

See: http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Feb/msg00078.html

Comment: I clicked to downvote Linuxios's answer when it was the top answer, and then SamCee's answer became the top answer, and (race condition?) my downvote mysteriously transferred from the one to the other. Apparently SO doesn't let you remove an accidental downvote. :(

Comment: Edit your answer so I can change my vote on it! And if you've got an authoritative source for the claim that it was fixed in Clang 3.2 / Xcode 4.5 (such as a Bugzilla ID), it would be great to add it to your edited answer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing a fundamental difference between Objective-C++ and C++, you **ALWAYS** pass the type of the template. The compiler doesn't try to be smart on this one. You must declare the type. In GCC G++, it fails with this message:

```
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hello.cpp:7: error: ‘t’ was not declared in this scope
```

Templates aren't supposed to be smart like that. You have to remember that C++ is statically typed, and type inference if very limited. In Objective-C, you can pass anything into an `id` and forget about it. Long story short, even if it does compile, it shouldn't, and don't depend on C++ and Objective-C to mix well. Objective-C++ may be a powerful combination, but remember that they will rarely work flawlessly with each other.

Comment: OK, that's not how templates work. Template types are actually inferred for functions (not for constructors, though).

Comment: @JonathanSterling: In what? Not in C++ from what I see. That gives me a compiler error. Is that an Objective-C thing? Or is it an Apple LLVM language extension (I used GCC).

Comment: @Linuxios: As far as *actual* C++ (ie: not Objective-C++) is concerned, the template types for a template function can be inferred from the given parameter types, where possible. If you have some actual C++ code for which this isn't working, it's probably because you're doing something else wrong or making inference impossible.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks. You learn something new every day here on SO. I always enjoy learning the little things like this in the comments.